# Disappearing and reverting events in Calendar

Tags: icloud, calendar

Calendar on OS X, which has always had trouble with disappearing events, is now waiting several minutes to perform its disapparation magic, so I an enter an appointment, wait a while to confirm that it stuck (a habit I've learned is essential over the years), be *sure* it’s safely recorded, and even then; poof! — it’s gone (or turned into a generic “New Event”).

I simply can’t rely on Calendar for anything any more!

Is there a way to configure Calendar so that appointments that I enter don't disappear or revert in this way?

Comment: Is it trying to sync to iCloud & failing? Poor connectivity, dodgy Wifi etc? It just has all the feel of 'server lag', dropped packets, high latency etc. If that is even vaguely a possibility, test with no internet connection & see if it holds until you do connect [or even if that fixes it entirely]. Even if inconvenient, it might be pointing the way.

Comment: I don't think so. If so the issue isn't on my side. I have fast reliable network connectivity. It does feel line a sync issue, but the problem seems to be on the Apple end of things. I've logged out and back in again, and this has persisted across several OS X upgrades (and one machine transfer).

Comment: Though unrelated to iCloud; I work helpline for an online gaming structure… where the opening 'fix' for anything that feels network-related is "Reboot your puter & all networking hardware & try again" By heck it's trite, I know, but the number of times it actually works…

Comment: I've done that several times. It has no effect (nor do updates, killing processes, or even machine transfers).

Comment: I had a feeling you would have done that, over such a long time period. I'm out of ideas, sorry.. but it still 'feels' like network latency

Comment: @Tetsujin: Could firewall be involved?

Comment: Possibly. I'd be tempted to bypass the whole lot for a test & try a Starbucks. Unless it's a Mac Pro, of course ;-)

Comment: @Tetsujin: Starbucks is no better. And I can confirm that at least in one case (there could be many others undiscovered) the reversion happened after more than an hour (perhaps days) and — weirdly — if I try to change it to what it should be, I get a suggested edit that corresponds to what it was, but if I choose that, I'm unable to apply it!

Comment: I had a similar feel (network) to start with when I started seeing the same thing. I am now sat here directly logged in through a browser to the iCloud account of my partner trying to fix it and ready to kill almost... We have removed potential conflicting information from any other devices. Turned off those devices. Killed calendar processes on this remaining machine, and it's having a problem getting things as simple as a calendar name change to stick. It has taken me at least half a dozen gos to get just re-ordering the calendars on iCloud to stay in the same order.

Comment: Even having got that to work it is refusing to remember beyond 10 minutes if it's set to share the calendars. I've been trying to remove a share with an account we no longer own and it keeps putting it back on and throwing away any new share data.

Did you ever find a way to sort the config to actually accept updates made?